# Querying the location data from MySQL on google maps

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps

Currently,I have created a page showing all the locations of the users (all from MySQL database) on google map. But because there are 5000+ user locations, it takes a long time to load the page.

I would like to make it more efficiently by only querying the user locations within certain area. (the area I am viewing)

What could I do to make it more efficient? Does google maps API support the feature that I want? I heard I can do geofencing mysql, but I cannot really find how to use it.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is the center of your map? The current location for a user or a fixed point?

Comment: @Ares the center of my map is the current location that the user is viewing.

Comment: How are you getting back the locations to javascript? What backend language are you using?

Comment: @Ares Now i am using php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do what you want. If you have the longitude and latitude of the users (which sounds like you do) then instead of loading all user locations `(select latitude, longitude from users)` then narrow down the location by specifying a range for the coordinates of your user, so your select looks something like this (in pseudo query)

```
select latitude, longitude from users where latitude between (user.latitude + whateverrangeyouwant and user.latitude - whateverrangeyouwant) AND longitude between (user.longitude + whateverrangeyouwant AND user.longitude - whateverrangeyouwant);
```

The range can probably be taken from the map.bounds property

You can then send this back to your script using a service that will then remove the markers from the map and add the one ones based on your service response. So your javascript would look something like this (in pseudo code)

`get user location;
send service request for user locations and get them back in an array
remove current markers
add new markers from service result`

The service in PHP probably look something like this:

```
 $minLat = $_REQUEST['lat'] - ($_REQUEST['dl'] / 2);
 $maxLat = $_REQUEST['lat'] + ($_REQUEST['dl'] / 2);
 $minLon = $_REQUEST['lon'] - $_REQUEST['dln'];
 $maxLon = $_REQUEST['lon'] + $_REQUEST['dln'];

 $query = 'SELECT  locations.latitude,
                   locations.longitude
           FROM locations
           WHERE (latitude BETWEEN ' . $minLat . '  AND  ' .  $maxLat . ') AND
                 (longitude BETWEEN ' . $minLon . ' AND ' . $maxLon. ')';

    }

    $query = DB::query($query);

    $json = array();

    while($location = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json[] = $location;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
    exit();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ^^